# What is the Rakghoul plague?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Recently while roaming the imperial fleet, there came a warning message saying that Tatooine has been hit by the Rakghoul plague, and visitors shouldn't go. Now I've seen med droids sell antidotes but the question is what is the Rakghoul plague? Does it do anything special like kill your character instantly or spawn a large group of Rakghouls and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://www.swtorstrategies.com/2012/04/swtor-world-events-are-happening-rakghoul-plague.html

It's a live event (if you're familiar with WoW it's like the Undead Invasion before WotLK) that has been deployed on the servers with the new patch. The link I provided should fill you in with all the informations you need, at least to start, considering it's unfolding right now.